# How can I randomly reward points for app usage

Tags: java, android, random, kotlin

I am working on an android app where user get points for using the app which can be used to unlock in-app features.

I have a function called `rewardPoints()` which generates random integer and I want it to get called randomly while the user is using the app. The points then gets added up in database.

```
fun rewardPoints() {
        var points = Random().nextInt((5-1) + 1)
}
```

How do I call the function `rewardPoints()` randomly while the user is using/interacting with the app?

Comment: I'd use a timer

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler) to post a [Runnable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable) that re-posts itself. Like so,

```
val handler = Handler()
handler.post({
    rewardPoints()
    handler.postDelayed(this, DELAY_TIME_MS)
})
```

You could kick this off in your Activity's `onResume` and stop it `onPause` to make sure it's only running when the app is active.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an observer on your activities, check whether you have active activities and when that's the case start a periodic task to award points.

Sample:

```
class MyApp : Application(), Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this)
    }

    var count: Int by Delegates.observable(0) { _, old, newValue ->
        when (newValue) {
            0 -> onBackground()
            1 -> if (old == 0) onForeground()
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity?) {
        count++
    }
    override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity?) {
        count--
    }


    fun onForeground() {
        Log.d("TAG", "start.")
        events.start()
    }

    fun onBackground() {
        Log.d("TAG", "stop.")
        events.cancel()
    }


    val events = object: CountDownTimer(Long.MAX_VALUE, 1000) {
        // is called once per second as long as your app is in foreground
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            if (ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100) < 5) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MyApp, "You earned a point.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        override fun onFinish() { /* will never happen */}
    }

    /* not needed */
    override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity?) {}
    override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity?) {}
    override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity?, outState: Bundle?) {}
    override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity?) {}
    override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {}
}
```

If you use architecture components Lifecycle, implementing above is even simpler with https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner and listening to the desired Lifecycle.Event